# Celery Worker not Inheriting Settings from Django App

Tags: python, django, celery

I am developing a django app that has to process large spreadsheets that users upload - so naturally I turned to celery and rabbitmq. I successfully setup the environment and the task completes in the background successfully except for one issue: I use several environment variables (defined in my apache vhost file and passed to django by mod_wsgi) in a db router class to determine which database to use (i.e. production vs staging vs dev):

```
class DbRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):

        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'auth'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'admin':
            return 'auth'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'contenttypes':
            return 'auth'
        else:

            environment = environment = os.environ['BH_ENVIRONMENT_NAME']

            if environment == "staging":
                return 'staging'
            if environment == "production":
                return 'production'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):

        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'auth'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'admin':
            return 'auth'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'contenttypes':
            return 'auth'
        else:

            ###########################################
            #This is where django raises the exception#
            ###########################################
            environment = os.environ['BH_ENVIRONMENT_NAME']

            if environment == "staging":
                return 'staging'
            if environment == "production":
                return 'production'

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name, **hints):
        return True
```

which works just fine in the regular django thread; however, when the background task attempts to use the db router I get the following key error (which seems to imply that `os.environ` dictionary is not available to the worker thread?):

```
[2018-02-16 14:23:01,516: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task 
exposures.tasks.process_exposure_file[27d7e651-e73e-49f1-bd20-8ab80b90d13a] 
raised unexpected: KeyError('BH_ENVIRONMENT_NAME',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/BeachHouse/bhvenv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/BeachHouse/bhvenv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bryan/PycharmProjects/BeachHouse/exposures/tasks.py", line 10, 
in process_exposure_file
exposure = Exposure.objects.get(pk=exposure_id)
File "/var/www/BeachHouse/bhvenv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/BeachHouse/bhvenv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 397, in get
num = len(clone)
File "/var/www/BeachHouse/bhvenv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 254, in __len__
self._fetch_all()
File "/var/www/BeachHouse/bhvenv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
File "/var/www/BeachHouse/bhvenv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 50, in __iter__
db = queryset.db
File "/var/www/BeachHouse/bhvenv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1109, in db
return self._db or router.db_for_read(self.model, **self._hints)
File "/var/www/BeachHouse/bhvenv/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/utils.py", line 258, in _route_db
chosen_db = method(model, **hints)
File "/home/bryan/PycharmProjects/BeachHouse/BeachHouse/db_routers.py", line 
16, in db_for_read
environment = os.environ['BH_ENVIRONMENT_NAME']
File "/var/www/BeachHouse/bhvenv/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in 
__getitem__
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'BH_ENVIRONMENT_NAME'
```

I attempted to fix this by adding the following to my settings.py file:

```
ENVIRONMENT_NAME = os.environ.get('BH_ENVIRONMENT_NAME')
```

and updating the db router to use `settings.ENVIRONMENT_NAME` - however, when I print this out in the celery worker terminal it's blank. My celery.py file is as follows (not sure if that's relevant or not?):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'BeachHouse.settings'

app = Celery('BeachHouse')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('BeachHouse.settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

so the question is: how do I pass the apache vhost variables to the celery workers - or alternatively, how do I get my django settings to this worker thread (that successfully load the apache variables)? I would like to stick with using the apache virtual host approach to define the variables if possible as there are many settings getting pulled from there.

Comment: This is more about how you're starting Celery than any of the Django code you've shown. If the environment variable is available to the server but not to the task worker, then it must be not set in whatever environment you're starting Celery from. How are you setting that variable? How are you starting Celery and Django?

Comment: you'll have to forgive me as I'm new to working with all these technologies - I'm working in Pycharm and using the local debugger to run django (and I'm setting the environment variables in the pycharm environment config for debugging), and I'm starting the worker from the Pycharm terminal - is that what you're talking about?